# Basics of using Docker-Compose and Kubernetes for NodeJs connecting to Mongo

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I am tasked with using docker-compose to bring up a nodejs express mongoose demo to test some stuff for work. Here is the task sorry i am new to this stuff and I just need to know how to approach this thank you :

Dockerize [node-express-mongoose-demo](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) and expose the site on a non-standard port (not 80/443).  Do not worry about configuring S3 for image storage as noted in the README.md file.  When the app is in production mode it expects the MongoDB connection string to be in the MONGOHQ_URL environment variable.

Add an NGINX container acting as a reverse proxy that routes requests sent to it on port 80/443 to the Node app container.  Any supporting services such as MongoDB should also be deployed as Docker containers (Don't use MongoHQ as the app's environment variable suggests).

Use Kubernetes to automate the deployment and management of the containers.  Eliminate as many single points of failure for your deployment as possible.

Comment: Do you have any experience with docker or kubernetes at all?

Comment: A little bit I have the basics of it down. I know how to create images and containers in docker and I know how to create yaml files for kubernetes.

Comment: I would start with creating containers in that case.  After manually creating them you can move on to Docker compose and migrate that to kubernetes.

Comment: @ForeverLiunx212 If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

@ForeverLiunx212 I would recommend you to get started with understanding the stack and running it locally using Docker-Compose, and then set it up on Kubernetes.

Running the [docker-compose](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file locally,
`docker-compose up -d`

This should get your app and mongo up and running, if not debug errors in your containers
`docker logs CONTAINER_NAME`

Deploying your stack to Kubernetes cluster.

- Setup Mongo as a statefulsets using k8s configs. Once you are comfortable, you can also tryout this [Mongo helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb)
- Setup your application with [nginx as reverse proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/)
- Expose your service to external world via ingress controller

Comment: Thank you you so muck for this response I will try this out and take it from there.